Why is the air speed of a general fan less than 500 meters per second?
I am confused. Since the thermal motion speed of air molecules is about 500 meters per second, why is the air speed of a general fan less than 500 meters per second?

To piggy back off gandalf61’s nice answer: the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution is orientation agnostic. It only gives you the probability of a certain speed for a molecule. Thus, if you think about “still” air, on average the particles are moving with zero velocity even though each one is moving quite quickly. But an object like a fan makes the average speed of some subset of molecules have a net orientation in a particular direction, which we feel as a rush of air.

@MattHanson  That is to say, the air molecules have a net velocity in the direction of the air's velocity? The fan blades make the air molecules have a net velocity in the direction of the air's velocity?

You can think of it as a shift in the average directional velocity of the particles, yes. Basically, the speed of the air molecules isn’t particularly different, but just redirected to have a useful net effect rather than just exerting pressure on the surfaces of objects in their vicinity.

Because thermal motion of individual air molecules is a random walk, whereas the speed of the air stream created by the fan is a co-ordinated movement of many molecules averaged over time.
Imagine millions of impatient and indestructible bumper cars bouncing off one another in a very slow moving traffic jam.

That is to say, the air molecules have a net velocity in the direction of the air's velocity? The fan blades make the air molecules have a net velocity in the direction of the air's velocity?
